# make: *** No rule to make target `main.o'

Tags: eclipse, makefile, avr

here is the output from the console in Eclipse:

```
 **** Build of configuration Debug for project FatFstest ****

make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `main.o', needed by `FatFstest.elf'.  Stop.
```

I am trying to build a project using the AVR plugin for Eclipse to test the [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) library. I first imported the FatFs code then created main.c file to implement it. After I tried building it the first time, I added the src folder of my project to my the directories list in Properties > AVR Compiler > Directories, and I still get the build error. Any help?

Here is my makefile:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(ASM_DEPS)),)
-include $(ASM_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(S_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(S_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
LSS += \
FatFstest.lss \

SIZEDUMMY += \
sizedummy \

AVRDUDEDUMMY += \
avrdudedummy \


# All Target
all: FatFstest.elf secondary-outputs

# Tool invocations
FatFstest.elf: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: AVR C Linker'
    avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,FatFstest.map -mmcu=atmega328p -o"FatFstest.elf" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

FatFstest.lss: FatFstest.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: AVR Create Extended Listing'
    -avr-objdump -h -S FatFstest.elf  >"FatFstest.lss"
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

sizedummy: FatFstest.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: Print Size'
    -avr-size --format=avr --mcu=atmega328p FatFstest.elf
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

avrdudedummy: FatFstest.elf
    @echo 'Invoking: AVRDude'
    /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR-20100115/bin/avrdude -pm328p -Uflash:w:FatFstest.hex:a
    @echo 'Finished building: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(ASM_DEPS)$(ELFS)$(LSS)$(AVRDUDEDUMMY)$(S_DEPS)$(SIZEDUMMY)$(S_UPPER_DEPS) FatFstest.elf
    -@echo ' '

secondary-outputs: $(LSS) $(SIZEDUMMY) $(AVRDUDEDUMMY)

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

main.c

```
#include <diskio.h>
#include <ff.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
   printf("hello world\n");
   return 0;
 }
```

subdir.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
C_SRCS += \
../src/diskio.c \
../src/ff.c \
../src/main.c 

OBJS += \
./src/diskio.o \
./src/ff.o \
./src/main.o 

C_DEPS += \
./src/diskio.d \
./src/ff.d \
./src/main.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
src/%.o: ../src/%.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: AVR Compiler'
    avr-gcc -I"/Users/nathannewcomb/Documents/Puzzles/FatFstest/src" -Wall -g2 -gstabs -O0 -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=1000000UL -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c -o"$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

objects.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

USER_OBJS :=

LIBS :=
```

sources.mk

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

O_SRCS := 
C_SRCS := 
S_UPPER_SRCS := 
S_SRCS := 
OBJ_SRCS := 
ASM_SRCS := 
OBJS := 
C_DEPS := 
ASM_DEPS := 
ELFS := 
LSS := 
AVRDUDEDUMMY := 
S_DEPS := 
SIZEDUMMY := 
S_UPPER_DEPS := 

# Every subdirectory with source files must be described here
SUBDIRS := \
src \
```

Comment: Could you isolate the problem by reducing your makefile to the *minimum* possible required to provoke the problem?  At the moment, we can't see the contents of all those includes, etc.

Comment: Check if $(OBJS) or $(USER_OBJS) has any rule to compile main.cc to main.o. Just search for "main" in all the make-files that are included and trace the compilation "tree" so that it can build the main.o. Maybe you have to add suck a rule!

Comment: @Oli I'm sorry. I just posted the makefile that eclipse generates automatically. Can you be more specific on what you want? I'm a confused.

Comment: @Nathan: What I mean is, that makefile is way too complex for anyone here to be able to debug without access to all the included files that it uses, nor access to your environment.  Your best bet is to manually edit the makefile to isolate the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Oli To be honest, that's why I am posting this question here. I'm not comfortable enough with makefiles to write my own for this type of project, and I wanted to see if the SO community could help me solve my problem. Tell me what you "included files" you need and I will be happy to post them.

Comment: I see you've posted the contents of the included files now.  I'm somewhat confused, as `$(OBJS)` contains `./src/main.o`, but the error message you've posted only talks about `main.o` (without the rest of the path).

Comment: @Oli Good catch. I originally put it in the root project directory by accident then moved it. I just deleted the subdir.mk file in the root directory and rebuilt. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It happened to me too, simply moving main.cpp in an another folder.

I try to clean out the project, but the problem persist, so I have deleted Debug folder, re-compile and it works!

Comment: should be accepted answer as this is the problem, the Debug directory caches a makefile which needs to be rebuilt after a source file moves.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the main.c in a directory, put it at the top of its project

Answer (score 0):

> I added the src folder of my project to my the directories list in
>   Properties > AVR Compiler > Directories

Remove this `/Users/nathannewcomb/Documents/Puzzles/FatFstest/src` folder and try to compile again.

In the subdir.mk file, the line :

```
avr-gcc -I"/Users/nathannewcomb/Documents/Puzzles/FatFstest/src" -Wall -g2 -gstabs -O0 -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=1000000UL -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c -o"$@" "$<"
```

should be become :

```
avr-gcc -Wall -g2 -gstabs -O0 -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=1000000UL -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c -o"$@" "$<"
```

This `src` folder is already added in source.mk file :

```
# Every subdirectory with source files must be described here
SUBDIRS := \
src \
```

Answer (score 0):

quoting eclipse - http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcdt_c_makefile.htm

Q2. My Console view says No rule to make target 'X'.

make -k clean all 
make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.
By default, the make program looks for a file most commonly called "Makefile" or "makefile". If it cannot find such a file in the working directory, or if that file is empty or the file does not contain rules for the command line goals ("clean" and "all" in this case), it will normally fail with an error message similar to those shown.

If you already have a valid Makefile, you may need to change the working directory of your build. The default working directory for the build command is the project's root directory. You can change this by specifying an alternate Build Directory in the Make Project properties. Or, if your Makefile is named something else (eg. buildFile.mk), you can specify the name by setting the default Build command to make -f buildFile.mk.

If you do not have a valid Makefile, create a new file named Makefile in the root directory. You can then add the contents of the sample Makefile (above), and modify it as appropriate.